# Running into socket saturation/IO Exceptions wen issuing more than 500 concurrent requests to Apache Solr index update

Tags: solr

I am using Apache Solr with Hitachi and running some load tests, I am creating a large number of Index update requests and using c# tasks to send them at the same time. 
If I keep my number below 500 then everything works fine, I can keep making multiple requests as long as at a time it does not exceed 500 requests

But if I increase that number I start getting IO Exception, connection has been terminated errors, all of them pointing to the socket saturation (no more socket available) problem

500 is not a lot of requests and we will have peak times where 1000's of users might be making changes that leads to index updates, I have explored setting Max http connection for a server in C# code and that works but that will limit the scalability and because the requests will be queued the average response time will increase.

Is there a way to change the number of concurrent connection Solr can handle.

Comment: How often are you committing these changes to the index? Are you using `commitWithin` or are you committing for each request? Are you using the default jetty configuration, or have you done any tuning of the bundled jetty server? Have you seen https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/high-load.html ?

Comment: We are not making any uncommitted request, every request is committed, we were thinking of changing that but we are not using workflows that can pick up any data loss. what happens if do not commit and then is some problem indexing that document?. Just played with container and heap memory but nothing else

Comment: The SOLR containers are running on RedHat 7.8. and the port ranges on the nodes is:  
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999